# Como executar codicos c# no navegador?

Tags: c#, aplicação-web

Há alguma forma de integrar HTML e C#?
Ou como fazer um Debug para C#?

Então, está pergunta estou fazendo para que outras pessoas, que sabem programa apps em C#, que estejam se aventurando no mundo Web acabem construindo um site em C# no lugar do JS, PHP ou outros.

Como citei na 2ª pergunta, um debug C#, para editores onlines, mais para verificar se o codigo esta correto e não a nenhum bug, sem a necessidade de executalo (como inteiramente um programa em si).

Comment: Direto no navegador? Tipo JavaScript?

Comment: @jbueno, sim tipo JavaScript

Comment: A princípio não. Não vou te dizer que é impossível, mas deve ser muito trabalho pra pouco resultado. Por que exatamente você precisa disso? Talvez, se explicar seu problema, podemos te mostrar uma solução (tenho certeza de que isso não é a solução mais viável)

Comment: @jbueno, tipo era apenas uma curiosidade tipo se a algum geito de integrar HTML e C#, como HTML e JS , Ruby e HTML, pois acheique isso poderia ajudar muitos iniciantes em Programações Web que ja Sabem Programar nesta linguagem. Ou no caso de uma construção de um editor online apenas um debug para C#

Comment: @Daniel o "J"eito é editar a pergunta e especificar melhor o que quer

Comment: @Daniel Me parece que você está confundindo um pouco as coisas. Ruby roda no servidor (da mesma forma que C#, PHP, Python, entre outras) e JavaScript roda no cliente (no browser). O melhor é você [edit] sua pergunta e ser mais específico, dê mais detalhes sobre sua dúvida. Mas, de qualquer forma, te aconselho a ler sobre ASP.NET.

Comment: @jbueno, ok, mas como falei não é uma Duvida e sim uma Curiosidade e enquanto a as Extensões apenas mostrei como um exemplo.

Comment: Não sei se é isso que você quer, mas pode rodar o C# direto nessa página: https://ideone.com/ escolha o C# na lista abaixo da caixa onde se digita o código.

Comment: @math, sim esatamente assim so que diretamente no meu site, mas isso ja qubra um galho : - ]

Comment: Entendi, você queria implementar o seu próprio compilador on line, assim como a https://www.codecademy.com/ tem, certo?

Comment: Tem este aqui também https://dotnetfiddle.net/

Comment: @math, sim isso mesmo

Comment: @jbueno, ok vou ver

Answer (score 1):

Não vou te falar que é impossível pois já vi gente fazendo até um kernel(SO) de Linux rodando através de javascript "embbedado" no Navegador.

[Emulador de Linux com Javascript](http://bellard.org/jslinux/)

Porém uma coisa é certa, qualquer solução que você quiser fazer direto no navegador não será possível escapar de fazê-la usando Javascript como linguagem intermediária funcionando como de interpretador/compiladora/executora do C# o que é genial porém super complexo.

Algumas soluções geralmente pegam um trecho de codigo, sobem ele para o servidor, executam lá e retornam o resultado em HTML.

Existem hoje muitos sites que simulam o resultado de um codigo C# que você poderá usar como plataforma de ensino por ex:

http://csharppad.com/

Abraço !

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível executar códigos C# direto no navegador do cliente, pois os códigos são executados no servidor e para o cliente somente é retornado o HTML puro.

O mesmo conceito vale para páginas ASP clássico, PHP, ASP.Net, etc.

O que é possível fazer é por meio de jQuery chamar uma instrução C# no servidor, essa instrução irá processar e fazer um retorno do HTML

Além de essa abordagem ser mais performática, você tem um ganho com segurança, porque, imagina escrever a string de conexão direto no navegador do cliente.

Exemplo de código postback com jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("DeleteMessage", "Home")",
    type: "POST",
    data: { messageid: GetCurrentMessageID(), mailbox: GetCurrentMailbox() },
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
         //Sucesso, faça algo
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
         //Erro
    }
});
```

Acho que assim você consegue ter um norte, esse código eu utilizo em uma aplicação com ASP.Net MVC, a página faz a chamada do código em postback e retorna para o cliente somente o que eu quero (Uma mensagem, uma grid, etc.)

Espero ter ajudado!